# Angular2 mock an @Attribute("name") value of a constructor via jasmine beforeEachProviders

Tags: jasmine, angular, angular2-routing

I have the following class for routing purposes:

```
export class LoggedInOutlet extends RouterOutlet {

  constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
    private router: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string) {
    super(_elementRef, _loader, router, nameAttr);
  }
```

Now I want to test this class with jasmine and looking for something like this:

```
provide(Attribute, {useValue: "123"}),
```

For the attribute value. Any ideas how to provide an Attribute for a jasmine mock?

Thanks.